# How can I scale only the 4k monitor on Kubuntu 22.04?

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors

I'm using Kubuntu 22.04. I have 2 monitors. One monitor is 4k resolution and the other is Full HD. How can I scale only the 4k monitor? When I scale the 4k monitor from Display configuration -> Global scale to 175%, the Full HD monitor goes to 175% along with it.

[image]

With `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 1.75x1.75` the picture became very pixelated.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal run:

```
export QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=$QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS"eDP-1-1=2"
```

Then log out and log back in.